# How could Appnext SDK start its own activity for its ads even if it's not in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android

I'm working with the AppNext ads SDK and I found inside the Interstitial ad a display function that calls `startActivity (new Intent (this.context, InterstitialActivity.class))`.
`InterstitialActivity` extends the `AppnextActivity` class, which in turn extends `Activity`.
My question is: How could they start its activity without registering the InterstitialActivity class at the Manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android SDK permits [merging manifests from multiple sources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge), including any libraries you depend on for your project. This way, such Android libraries could register their components like Activity or Service without the app developer touching the main `AndroidManifest.xml` at all.

Comment: I compile sdk library of appnext in build.gradle, so the declaration in manifest can be replaced by java code of sdk?Or how did they make it possible to start the activity without declaring it in my AndroidManifest.xml file. I have read through the material but are still limited by my language

Comment: @Chanh You app has `AndroidManifest.xml`. The library also has its own `AndroidManifest.xml`. When you build it, the build system (involving Gradle) combines all `AndroidManifest.xml` files into a single (compiled) `AndroidManifest.xml` and puts it into your APK.

Comment: Thank @minmaxavg, I understand now